# What Google API keys are needed to make SXA Location Finder work?

Tags: sxa

I am following below link for location filter and showing it on map.
https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html

When I start searching in the text box, I get below error:

[image]

It says : **This API project is not authorised to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developer Console.**

Need to confirm if, for locations to be populated in location finder, is it compulsory to check all the 3 options while generating the API key ? I am not sure if all the 3 options need to be checked. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google Maps changed their APIs in June 2018. There are not free anymore as you have discovered and you need to create project and enable APIs there. Have no worries. You have 200$ limit that you can spent free of charge every month.

I think that for Location finder you will need to have "Places API" enabled but to really unlock full functionality of SXA Maps component, follow below steps.

Head to your project api list:

https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/api-list?project_name

but you will be redirected to a page with list of apis:

https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/new?project=project_name

which looks like this:

[image]

Enabled all APIs, with "API" at the end of their name + Places API for Web, like this:

[image]

with this list of enabled APIs at the end:

[image]

After these changes finally SXA map component with Google Maps started to work:

[image]

Once again. Have no worries enabling all of those APIs. You have 200$ month budget to spent and you are paying only for services that you use. You are not paying by number of enabled APIs!

More details can be found here:
https://tothecore.sk/2018/09/07/sitecore-sxa-set-google-maps-for-map-component-with-latest-pricing-changes